# account id & bitcoin amount & message ?-> show website content

Tags: transactions, wallet, address

I am planning to make an website / wordpress plugin. Site will ask visitor's `account id`.

Site will show content only if a bitcoin transaction with specified  `account id` & `bitcoin amount` & `message` exist.

My big plan let visitor to track how a software have been made. Like in a version control system, like in Github visitor could track changes. But!! certain changes / commits the developer could charge some dollar.

My specific question is: Can I **query** all the **bitcoin transactions** back to the past and filter with a predicate contains the following fields: `account id = 'abc'`  & `bitcoin amount = 123` & `message = 'def'`?

Comment: Do you have a specific technical question? This site is better suited for technical questions, rather than forum-style request for comments.

Comment: right, I fine-tuned my question